# MongoDB aggregation replacing mulitple calculation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get avgBMI, maxBMI and maxBMI from my collection.

```
var bmi =  db.people.aggregate(
    [   
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id: 1,
                avgBmi: {$avg: {$divide: [{$toDouble:"$weight"},{$pow: [{$divide:[{$toDouble:"$height"},100]},2]}]}},
                minBmi: {$min: {$divide: [{$toDouble:"$weight"},{$pow: [{$divide:[{$toDouble:"$height"},100]},2]}]}},
                maxBmi: {$max: {$divide: [{$toDouble:"$weight"},{$pow: [{$divide:[{$toDouble:"$height"},100]},2]}]}}
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

that's working but it's nasty...

https://mongoplayground.net/p/LxJU8KmRzq2

How can I replace the procedure for calculation to stop doing it 3 times?

Comment: Can you post please sample data / expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$project` stage to assign your operation to a single field and then use that field inside the `$group` stage.

```
db.people.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "cal": {
      "$divide": [
        { "$toDouble": "$weight" },
        { "$pow": [{ "$divide": [{ "$toDouble": "$height" }, 100] }, 2] }
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": 1,
    "avgBmi": { "$avg": "$cal" },
    "minBmi": { "$min": "$cal" },
    "maxBmi": { "$max": "$cal" }
  }}
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/KKCrxBZA_kO

Comment: That's it, I tried $project before, but it seems I did wrong... thank you